# Need Image Effect Library for Android IOS both

Tags: android, ios, image, effect

I am developing Photo Sharing app in Android and iOS, in that I want to add image effects like instagram app, so I need Image Effect Library which are available in Android and iOS both.

Please help me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use this Aviary SDK: 
https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android

Thanks.

Comment: Signups are disabled. You may log into an existing account.

Comment: how to signup in aviary for eclipse

Comment: could you signup since then or still cant signup?

Answer (score 1):

Check this awesome SDK:
[Aviary SDK](https://developers.aviary.com/)

I think they turned off to signup for free. You can check code for Android here :
http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-image-filters.html

Comment: Signups are disabled. You may log into an existing account.

Comment: how to signup in aviary for eclipse